# Maintaining a WP7 and WP8 version in one solution

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Basically, what i have is one solution with two projects targeting Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8. I have linked the pages and classes from my WP7 project to WP8 project (add as link), also each project contains two separate pages `TestPage.xaml` and `TestPageWP8.xaml`.

In the WP8 project i have added additional `Conditional compilation symbols` **WP8**. So in my MainPage i have something like:

```
        private void onButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
#if WP8
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPageWP8.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
#else
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
#endif   
        }
```

The problem is that i can not open `TestPageWP8`, the application always opens `TestPage`

My StartUp Project is WP7, i have Nokia Lumia 920 and 610. I am missing something but what?

Thank you!

Comment: On a side note, using conditional compilation is not the best practice. Try using a proper MVVM approach, it will avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: There's a [great tutorial on the Nokia Developer wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Co-development_for_Windows_Phone_7/8_and_Windows_8_guide) which covers WP7, WP8 and Win8 code sharing within the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it navigates to `TestPage`, it means either that the conditional compilation symbol wasn't properly defined, or that you're running the WP7 version of the app... Which seems to be the case since your startup project is the WP7 version.

Comment: thanks for your reply, so then how can i choose between StartUp projects

Comment: In the Solution Explorer right click a project and "Set as startup project". Just make sure you change projects when deploying to WP7 and WP8.

Comment: @SeeSharp As danielzoro mentioned, make sure to set the WP8 project as startup project when deploying to a WP8 phone/emulator. Also, to make sure you're executing the right one, you can go in the configuration manager (in the debug/release listbox in visual studio, select "Configuration Manager"), then uncheck the "Deploy" checkbox in front of the project you're not using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(8, 0))
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPageWP8.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
else
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer that was my first idea, but i have got an exception "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException"

Comment: What is your target whindows phone OS Version? You can see this information in Project properties.

Comment: WP7, what i wanna do is to use `SpeechSynthesizer` if the phone is WP8

Comment: It's not possible to use `SpeechSynthesizer` with WP7 target OS Version. I think that you will need to run each app version with the right Target Version, and I also suggest that you use WP8 target version for WP8 for a better performence.

Comment: i know but, you can add WP8 functionality in an existing WP7 application through reflections

Answer (score 1):

If you have as a startup project the WP7 version, then the "WP8" compilation symbol is not defined in this solution and you'll navigate to the TestPage.xaml.
If you want to navigate to TestPageWP8.xaml, you need to set as the startup project the WP8 project.
Also make sure **the compilation symbol WP8 is actually defined** in your WP8 project - right click the project, go to Properties and check the Build tab, if WP8 is defined next to the "SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE" symbols.

Comment: my problem was coming from sharing App.xaml

Answer (score 1):

Using this example code from [MangoPollo library](https://mangopollo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), you can make your own `SpeechSynthesizer` library

```
Type taskDataType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.MapsTask, Microsoft.Phone");
object task = taskDataType.GetConstructor(new Type[] {}).Invoke(null);
Utils.SetProperty(task, "SearchTerm", SearchTerm);
if (ZoomLevel > 0)
    Utils.SetProperty(task, "ZoomLevel", ZoomLevel);
Utils.SetProperty(task, "Center", Center);
MethodInfo showmethod = taskDataType.GetMethod("Show");
showmethod.Invoke(task, new object[] {});
```

Comment: thanks you bro,i am sorry, but i don't see how this is relevant, really :D

Comment: @SeeSharp just find the library you need to use in speech and wrap it like MangoPollo library wraps the MapsTask library available only in WP8.